# Cannot login to Wordpress on one device: login refreshes/an error was encountered whilst trying to authenticate

Tags: login

I hope someone can help me with an issue I’m having. I’m trying to login to my WordPress dashboard but I’m constantly either getting the login page simply refreshing or occasionally an red error message saying “ERROR: An error was encountered whilst trying to authenticate. Please try again.”

I’m actually able to login without an issue on another computer and I’ve tried all the suggested steps I’ve seen elsewhere: I’ve cleared the browsers cookies/cache, tried a different browser altogether, disabled all plugins, disabled my theme, removed Wordfence and deleted all the tables etc. via the Wordfence Assistant plugin… I still cannot login on this specific PC. I’ve contacted my hosting provider who have checked and can’t see any reason why I cannot log in.

I’ve tried to reset my password but strangely on the affected PC I can’t even do this since putting in either the email address or password on the Lost Password page gives another error “Error: please enter a username or email address.”

Most recently I also regenerated my .htaccess file and this also hasn't solved the issue. The PC I'm trying to log in from is clear of any malware or viruses and I'm stumped as to the reason why I cannot get past the login screen on just that particular device. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I thought it was probably Wordfence related also- however the issue still occurs even after disabling Wordfence and using the Wordfence Assistant plugin to remove all the settings/tables etc.

I've checked on the debug tools and can't see anything along the lines of what you described unfortunately. I am not using Cloudflare or any similar tools.

Comment: That error is definitely coming from Wordfence not WordPress, from it's login.<hash>.js. Look in your browser debug tools for a request with action=wordfence_ls_authenticate and see if there's anything useful in the response body.

Comment: That all said if it's just one PC it does sound like a caching issue, although I can't explain why a completely different browser wouldn't fix it. Do you have Cloudflare or some other CDN? (not sure why that would affect one PC only though)